# What does "bulk silicon" mean?

Tags: solid-state-physics, soft-question, material-science, definition, nanoscience

The definition of the term "bulk" depends on the context, and I don't find the exact meaning of "bulk" when talking about materials.

[For example](https://books.google.es/books?id=EWMQ0iy4sUcC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=what+does+bulk+silicon+mean+in+physics&source=bl&ots=dE0RJo69K8&sig=ylGWL169jPXQuYcLhTTuoe3_7qQ&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH9f6Z9JPQAhWsJMAKHQSjAG4Q6AEIYTAJ#v=onepage&q=what%20does%20bulk%20silicon%20mean%20in%20physics&f=false): "The photoluminiscense emission from the bulk silicon sample is significantly sharper then the emission from the silicon nanoparticle sample."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with you in that the term "bulk" sometimes used a bit vaguely but in the example you gave it is relatively clear. It distinguishes the nanoparticle silicon from bulk silicon in photoluminiscense emission. Here bulk means what you would get for, say, silicon wafer.

The change in physical properties for different structures of the same material is an active research area. For example, physical properties of gold can be different for different gold surfaces, for gold nanoparticles in suspension, for gold nanoparticles supported on different substrates or for bulk gold.

Answer (score 0):

"Bulk" can have two meanings. Here it means that the material is so large that size does not matter (asymptotic value). Or it can mean inside, away from surfaces.